# enable_shared_from_this returns bad_weak_ptr error

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, enable-shared-from-this

I am using boost library in my project. While I was writing rest http client code I got this error.

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::__1::bad_weak_ptr: bad_weak_ptr

```
template <typename M>
 21 class Http: public std::enable_shared_from_this<Http<M>>
 22 {
 23     M* message_;
 24     bool isSubscribe_;
 25     boost::asio::io_context io_;
 26     boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver_;
 27     boost::beast::tcp_stream stream_;
 28     boost::beast::flat_buffer buffer_;
 29     boost::beast::http::request<boost::beast::http::empty_body> req_;
 30     boost::beast::http::response<boost::beast::http::string_body> res_;
 31     std::function<void(M*)> callback_;
 32 
 33     void SetUpRestHeader() {
 34         req_.method(boost::beast::http::verb::get);
 35         req_.target(message_ -> header_ -> target_);
 36         req_.set(boost::beast::http::field::host, message_ -> header_ -> host_);
 37         req_.set(boost::beast::http::field::user_agent, BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING);
 38 
 39         resolver_.async_resolve(message_ -> header_ -> host_
 40                 , message_ -> header_ -> port_
 41                 , boost::beast::bind_front_handler(
 42                     &Http::OnResolve
 43                     , this -> shared_from_this()));
 44     }
 45 

.......

128     explicit Http()
129         :io_{}
130         , resolver_(io_)
131         , stream_(io_)
132     {
133         message_ = new M;
134     }
135 
136     M RequestRestMessage()
137     {
138         auto ptr = this -> shared_from_this();
139         isSubscribe_ = false;
140         SetUpRestHeader();
141     }
142   };

151 int main()
152 {
153     Http<binance::ServerTime> http;
154     http.RequestRestMessage();
155 }
```

Error occurred even though I didn't call shared_from_this in a constructor. Please share your wisdom. Thanks!

Comment: Read c++ reference regarding `enable_shared_from_this`. The error is obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a look at [std::enable_shared_from_this: Examples](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this#Example) you can see this:

```
 // Bad: shared_from_this is called without having std::shared_ptr owning the caller 
try {
  Good not_so_good;
  std::shared_ptr<Good> gp1 = not_so_good.getptr();
} catch(std::bad_weak_ptr& e) {
  // undefined behavior (until C++17) and std::bad_weak_ptr thrown (since C++17)
  std::cout << e.what() << '\n';    
}
```

Your `Http<binance::ServerTime> http;` creates an object with [automatic storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration#Storage_duration), and it is (and must not) owned by a `shared_ptr` due to that.  Your `http.RequestRestMessage()` then invoces `this -> shared_from_this` and that is the reason why you get that error.

[std::enable_shared_from_this::shared_from_this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this)

> It is permitted to call `shared_from_this` **only on a previously shared object**, i.e. on an object managed by `std::shared_ptr` (in particular, shared_from_this cannot be called during construction of *this).
>
> Otherwise the behavior is undefined (until C++17) `std::bad_weak_ptr` is thrown (by the `shared_ptr` constructor from a default-constructed `weak_this`) (since C++17).

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge! I will figure out a reason for the error

Comment: @wwwwe as I said the reason for the error is `Http<binance::ServerTime> http;` which creates an object with automatic storage duration. `shared_form_this` has to be called on an object owned by a shared pointer.